# How to run type object in sql developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I had a procedure, which contains TYPE OBJECT as Input.

1. When i click run procedure it shows RUN PLSQL popup.
2. Then i click input value box, it wont respond.

How can i feed input for Procedure with type object in sql developer tool?

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: If the issue is with SQL Developer then you should also include the version you are using; and if it's old check if you still have the same issue in the [current version](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html).

Comment: @AlexPoole Am using Version 4.1.3.20

Comment: @RobertoHernandez code is in live, so i cant post here... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you have a type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE my_type AS OBJECT (
  value1 NUMBER,
  value2 DATE
);
```

and a procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure (
  in_type_value IN MY_TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

Then the simplest way of running it is to write an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```sql
DECLARE
  value MY_TYPE := MY_TYPE( 42, SYSDATE );
BEGIN
  my_procedure( value );
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03cc86d9c496c67cde0f0b28f476bb38)*

and then run it as a script using <kbd>F5</kbd> or the "Run Script" [image: run script] button.